# Explaining sed, grep and cut syntax

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am analyzing a batch file and there is a line that it edit a text file (input) and making a txt file (output).

The batch is using three helping tools.exe: `grep`, `sed` and `cut`. I tried to read their manual use but it wasn't easy.

The line is:

```
type input.txt | sed "s#""#'#g" | grep -o "class='name[^>]*" | sed -n "/id=/p" | grep -o "surname=[^>]*" | cut -d"'" -f2 >output.txt
```

I want to know how the line is interpreted? What are the rules? Is there a smarter way of doing this (for example using one tool instead of all three)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add to jeb's answer, although it covers most of what you asked. 
These three commands are emulated commands ported from Linux, and they do the following:

1. `sed`: a stream editor for filtering and transforming text.
2. `grep`: a tool for printing lines matching a pattern.
3. `cut`: a tool for cutting out selected portions of each line of a file.

I recommend that you read more about these three commands by either typing `man <command name>` in Linux, or Googling that same string (for instance, "[man grep](https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL452IL452&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=man+grep)").
Also, look up [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX). Though they are usually unclear for beginners, they are a common and compact way for representing patterns.

Regarding the specific usage in the question:

> `sed "s#""#'#g"`

For each line, this replaces any quotation marks (`""`) with an apostrophes (`'`).

> `grep -o "class='name[^>]*"`

This prints only the part of the line starting with `class='name` but without a following `>`.

> `sed -n "/id=/p"`

By default Sed prints every line. On the other hand, `sed -n "<some pattern> /p"` prints only the lines that match the specified pattern. In this case, Sed prints only the lines containing `id=`.

> `grep -o "surname=[^>]*"`

This prints only the part of the line that starts with `surname=name'` but without a following `>`.

> `cut -d"'" -f2`

This parses each line as successive fields separated by an apostrophe (`'`), and picks the second one.

Everything is *piped*, meaning that the output of the each command serves as input for the next command to the right. The contents of "input.txt" are fed into the Sed command, the output of which is then fed into the grep command, and so on. The final output is obviously printed into a new file named "output.txt".

And yes, like jeb mentioned, this looks like an awkward solution, because everything here can be done `sed` alone, presumably by only one or two commands.

Comment: +1, Also nice, but I suppose there isn't a difference between `grep "class='name[^>]*"` and `grep "class='name"` as grep outputs always the complete line.

Comment: @jeb I think there is. In the former grep would not display lines containing with `class='name>` at all, and in the latter it would.

Comment: I've tested it and can't see any difference, as `[^>]*` should find empty or multiple characters which are not `>`, that is always true

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less easy.

Splitting it to single commands:

`sed "s#""#'#g"` is equivalent to `sed "s/""/'/g"`, which will replace each quote with a `'` character.

`grep -o "class='name[^>]*"` will catch only the lines with the text `class='name` and the `-o` switch should prefix the output with `STDIN:` ( don't know why this should be useful).

`sed -n "/id=/p"` will catch only lines containing  the text `id=`.

`grep -o "surname=[^>]*"` will catch only the lines with the text `surname=`.

`cut -d"'" -f2` will cut the line into parts, The parts are seperated by `'` (`-d'`) and you get the second field (`-f2`)

Yes, this looks like a fast hack solution, this could be solved with sed alone.
Especially when the order of the single texts are in a fixed order, like:
`<class="name17" id=13> <surname=Frank>`

Comment: @EitanT - Add yours, perhaps you can explain it better :-)

Answer (score 0):

The | character is the pipe character. It is used to pipe the output of one command to the input of another.

The > character is the redirect character. It redirects the standard output to a file.

So in your example the process starts with the *type* command:

```
type input.txt
```

This sends the *input.txt* to standard output which is then piped into the input of the next command:

```
sed "s#""#'#g"
```

and so on and so on through the other piped *grep* and *sed* commands.

The final *cut* command uses the > character to redirect it's output to the *output.txt* file.

```
cut -d"'" -f2 >output.txt
```

Comment: thank you , but I wanted to know what the grep and sed commands do :sed "s#""#'#g"
grep -o "class='name[^>]*"
sed -n "/id=/p"
grep -o "surname=[^>]*"
cut -d"'" -f2